# Emanuel Lasker, Max Noether, and Emmy Noether

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ho.history-overview

In 1900, Emanuel Lasker (world chess champion from 1894 to 1921) received his Ph.D. under Max Noether.  In 1905, Lasker published a theorem that Emmy Noether generalized in 1921, now well known as the Lasker-Noether theorem.  Aside from official papers related to Lasker's dissertation, do there exist records, correspondence, or anecdotes that involve Lasker's connections to either Max Noether or his daughter?

Comment: You could ask Jeremy Gray.  His paper on “Algebraic Geometry from Noether to Noether” is silent on correspondence or anecdotes but covers the relevant published record.

Comment: There's a well-known biography of Lasker written by Hannak called "Emanuel Lasker: The Life of a Chess Master" (with a foreword by Einstein). Maybe you could find something there.

Answer (score 4):

I'm a chess player and I read various books on and by Emanuel Lasker (he's in my pic!). In none of them, including the biographies by J. Hannak (mentioned in a comment) and B.S. Weinstein, I recall any significant reference to exchanges with Emmy Noether.

In [Emmy Noether – Mathematician Extraordinaire](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bfm:978-3-030-63810-8/1) by David E. Rowe (Springer, 2021) there's the following interesting paragraph (p. xvi), which at least contains Rowe's view on the significance of Emmy Noether's generalization.

> Noether’s other great achievement came in her earlier paper [Noether 1921b].
> Here she was able to place Emanuel Lasker’s decomposition theorem for ideals in
> a ring of polynomials on a much broader and clearer basis. The building blocks in
> this case were the primary ideals introduced by Lasker, but instead of five axioms
> Noether essentially only needed one restriction, namely, that the ring does not
> contain an infinitely ascending chain of ideals. This property was not new, but
> Emmy Noether was the first to recognize its central importance. This is why rings
> that satisfy the ascending chain condition (acc) are today called Noetherian rings.
> She later made this acc condition the first of her five axioms in [Noether 1927a].
> Noether’s structure theorem for polynomial rings was of great importance for the
> algebraization of algebraic geometry. Her father had proved a fundamental theorem for this discipline in 1871, which later served as the foundation for the work
> of the “Italian school.” However, his daughter took up earlier results of Hilbert
> and Lasker in order to lay the foundation for a new and far more general direction
> in algebraic geometry based on polynomial ideals. Yet even more important than
> these results were Noether’s methods, which clearly revealed the strength of her
> conceptual arguments compared with earlier more computational methods. Her
> goal throughout was to make everything as transparent as possible, and her most
> important works can still be read today with interest and understanding, a rare
> achievement in mathematics.